# Testing a RESTful API with POSTs from Python

Tags: python, api, http

I'm trying to test a RESTful interface I'm working on (I'm using this one: [codeigniter-restserver](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/)), and I'd like to use Python.

`GET`s seem to be working okay, but I'm having trouble with `POST`s. I'm not asking about the ins & outs of this library, rather I'm just trying
to figure out how to test `POST`ing with Python. This is what I've got:

```
import httplib, urllib

params = urllib.urlencode({
    'sentence':     'esta es una frase',
    'translation':  'this is a sentence'
})

headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Accept":       "text/plain"
}

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("localhost:80")
conn.request("POST", "/myapp/phrase", params, headers)

response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason

data = response.read()
conn.close()
```

Is this script sufficient as a way to test `POST`ing? I've seen a lot of requests on SO about people looking for GUI tools to do this (Firefox plugins, [etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435838/gui-http-client))
but for me the whole point of building a RESTful app in the first place is to have an API I can script to to modify the db quickly. (Populate it with data
from a JSON file, whatever.)

Am I on the right track with this Python-based approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POST is usually done via higher level function urllib2.

```
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Answer (score 21):

writing directly to `httplib` is fine, but rather low level.

check out the [Requests](http://python-requests.org) module.  It is a very simple and pythonic approach to crafting and sending http requests.

```
import requests

requests.post(url, data={}, headers={}, files={}, cookies=None, auth=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Nap](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/nap) which is just a wrapper for requests but makes it convenient to call e.g. HTTP APIs.

Example usage:

```
from nap.url import Url
api = Url('http://httpbin.org/')

response = api.post('post', data={'test': 'Test POST'})
print(response.json())
```

More examples: https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/nap#examples

Disclaimer: I wrote nap.